# PHP: how do I get values of csv based on specified column?

Tags: php, parsing, csv

For example I wanted to do something like

php sample.php [csv file] [column name]

it should display all data based on the specified column name. My code below just gets the first column but I wanted it to be a variable based on column name

CURRENT CODE

```
function getCSV($csv){
    $file = fopen($csv, 'r');
    while (!feof($file) ) {
        $lines[] = fgetcsv($file, 1024);
    }
    fclose($file);
    return $lines;
}

$csv = getCSV($argv[1]);
foreach ($csv as $values) {
    $row1[] = $values[0];
}
print_r($row1);
```

SAMPLE CSV

```
ID,Name
1,Amy
2,Ana 
3,Ava
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
php sample.php sample.csv ID
1
2
3

php sample.php sample.csv Name
Amy
Ana
Ava
```

How do I do this?

Comment: take each csv row and explode

Comment: `explode` can be tricky if you're relying on consistent delimiters, and it'll fail on delimiters embedded in values.

Comment: Try to `print_r($csv);` after you set `$csv` from the `getCSV()` function. See what it looks like at that point, and that might help you loop over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for all your help, eventually got it.

```
function getColumn($csv, $column){
    $header = array_shift($csv);
    $col = array_search($column, $header); 
    foreach ($csv as $row) {      
        $array[] = $row[$col]; 
    }
    return $array;
}
```